# sharing and updating a variable among multiple threads without synchronisation in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to simulate a 100 m running race program in java using multithreading. In this attempt I made a Atomic integer variable which should be common to all threads. This variable should increase by 1 after each thread crosses 100. unfortunately the result is not as expected.This is my attempt at the program.

```
    package running;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
    public class Employee implements Runnable{
    AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger();

public void run() {

for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" " + i);
        try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(i==100)
        {
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is in "+j.incrementAndGet()+" place");

        }
}
} 

public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
Employee e= new Employee();
Thread a= new Thread(e,"First");
Thread b= new Thread(e,"Second");
Thread c= new Thread(e,"Third");
Thread d= new Thread(e,"Fourth");
Thread f= new Thread(e,"Fifth");
a.start();
b.start();
c.start();
d.start();
f.start();

}
}
```

To demonstrate my problem in an understandable way I have added a print statement to check the running of the threads in the code . Here is the last 10 lines of the output.

```
Second 100
Fourth 100
Third 100
Fifth 100
First 100
Fourth is in 3 place
Third is in 1 place
Second is in 2 place
Fifth is in 4 place
First is in 5 place
```

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44645415/edit)

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You say "unexpected result" ... but heck: what is the actual result; and what did you expect?

Comment: once a thread crosses 100 that variable should increase by 1. and should print that thread name is in j th place. Actual result the j is coming randomly for random threads

Answer (score 1):

I don't see unexpected results.  when I run your code I get:

```
First is in 1 place
Third is in 3 place
Second is in 4 place
Fifth is in 2 place
Fourth is in 5 place
```

if I run the code again, I get this:

```
First is in 1 place
Second is in 2 place
Fifth is in 4 place
Fourth is in 3 place
Third is in 5 place
```

as expected, the results are not always the same. and the AtomicInteger is not losing any update.

if you want the results to be displayed in order, you need to synchronize the part of the code that registers the results. (to make sure that the first thread that reaches 100 will write that information before the next thread reaches 100)  for example, see below:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Employee implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger();
    private static Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        Thread a = new Thread(e, "First");
        Thread b = new Thread(e, "Second");
        Thread c = new Thread(e, "Third");
        Thread d = new Thread(e, "Fourth");
        Thread f = new Thread(e, "Fifth");
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        d.start();
        f.start();

        a.join();
        b.join();
        c.join();
        d.join();
        f.join();

        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(queue.remove());
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (queue) {
                if (i == 100) {
                    queue.add(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is in " + j.incrementAndGet() + " place");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The real thing is that the **expectation** by the OP isn't clear; and most likely: incorrect.

Comment: yes the result should not be the same. when u ran my code u got the i values along with the thread names u will see that the threads will reach 100 at some point . what I want is after they reach 100 they should be printed 1,2,3,4,5 place in the same order they reached 100

Comment: I edited my answer so the results are printed in the same order as they reached 100